# Does Marlin already have a way to define auto Z-offset strain gauge?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, z-probe, print-axis-offset

My Ender 3 v3 SE printer is still really new so I understand the info is limited. I'm trying to build a version of the latest Marlin FW that will work I've already redefined the pins that are different however `PA4 CLK` and `PC6 SDO` are undefined currently which is for the strain gauge or whatever they're using is a 4-wire sensor. I would imagine this could work as a second Z probe `Z1_PROBE` then take the difference between the Z probes.

My questions:

- How do I define the sensor pin?
- Is it baked in already to calculate the Z-offset between two probes?